# ShellIpcClient and NonCelloThread errors java

Tags: java, javafx

I have a strange "problem" in a Java project. This is the method where the error is:

```
@FXML
public void showJavaDoc() {
     final String JAVADOC_HOMEPAGE_PATH = "JavaDoc/index.html";
     File javaDocHomePage = new File(JAVADOC_HOMEPAGE_PATH);
     if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
         try {
             Desktop.getDesktop().browse(javaDocHomePage.toURI());
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             System.exit(1);
         }
     }
}
```

It shows me these errors:

```
[8100:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:116:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_giuse_shell 
[4716:NonCelloThread] thumbnail_util_win.cc:115:LoadBitmapFromPngResource Can't find PNG resource 0.** 
[8100:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:116:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_giuse_shell 
[4716:NonCelloThread] ctxmenu.cc:210:GenerateContextMenu Context menu IPC request failed with status: Status::UNKNOWN_STATUS
```

The strange fact is that this error is shown in IntelliJ terminal when I click on the button which opens my browser to show the documentation, which is correctly shown... and the program still run correctly.

From what can these error depend?

Comment: I think you're right, I just checked and it seems there is a Google drive problem on my own pc, I'll try to reinstall it and see what's happen

Comment: Replaced comments with an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would appear to by a google drive operation error.

Perhaps you have the folder synchronized using [Google Drive for desktop software](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7491144?hl=en), which intercepts file system requests.  And, perhaps, that software is currently failing.

So, likely local storage still works, but the file system isn't getting correctly synchronized to Google Drive, which is why it might be complaining.

I guess this because of this text in your error message:

```
Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_giuse_shell
```

Comment: I encountered similar warnings when using other programs to write files. Launching Google Drive solved it. (Google Drive prolly didn't quit correctly last time.)